# Ubuntu18.04 and Mate1.20 desktop environment in container

Tags: mate

I installed mate desktop environment on Ubuntu18.04 within a Singularity container by using

```
apt install -y ubuntu-mate-core
```

I copied my customized background image to /usr/share/backgrounds and added an entry to the xml file, so that my customized image is in the background list.

However, after login, the default wallpaper is always 'No Desktop background'.

I want to set the default wallpaper to my customized one, is there a configuration file somewhere I can edit to make the customized image always the background wallpaper?

Also, every time after login there's a bluetooth exception

> org.freedesktop.DBus.ServiceUnknown: The name org.blueman.Mechanism
>   was not provided by any .service files

I don't require bluetooth at all, how can I disable this?

Thanks